# VPS - root - shell: tweaking php to import 20mb file with phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, import

**System:** VPS, 1GB RAM, 1.2GHZ

**Access:** root, shell, anything

**Versions:** PHP 5.4.16,phpMyAdmin 4.2.7, 5.5.37 MariaDB, Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS 7)

**Task:** Import a 20mb (300k rows, 20 columns) sql dumb into phpMyAdmin

**Result:** Warning: "You probably tried to upload too large file"

**documentation:** http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems

i already tweaked in php.ini:

*upload_max_filesize
memory_limit 
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize*

i also used ftp to upload the .sql to the server - it should not depend on upload configs...

What else could i do? Where is the bottleneck?

Please consider i want to avoid BigDump..

thanks

Comment: Why use phpmyadmin for this at all?  The documentation link you provided lists using the 'source' command from within the mysql client.  That has nothing to do with BigDump.

Comment: What are the values of your php.ini Tweaks? Of course you could just upload the .sql file on your shell account instead and import it with e.g.: cat file.sql | mysql databasename

Answer (score 0):

you will have to change the mysql config to /etc/mysql/my.cf there you must update or add

```
max_allowed_packet = 21M
```

or higher, and also their is a setting in phpmyadmin folder.

Please note that you can use K for kilobyte, M for megabyte and so on.

Comment: hi. this folder does NOT exists. also there is NO setting in phpmyadmin folder. don't know why the upvote though...

Comment: that is the default folder for Ubuntu system where you can find the  settings file.It may differ in CentOS or other operating systems.
this is also true about the PhpMyAdmin installation.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment, I will just answer here.

On most systems (RHEL especially), there's a file in **/etc** called **my.cnf** - in that file there shouldn't be much, besides a few lines. Simply just add:

```
max_allowed_packet = 21M
```

Or higher. You can change the value to any you wish, just do not change it too low (below 21M, as it will refuse the file to get uploaded), nor too high - in case of a loop of some sort.

However, also be sure that the line is in the [mysqld] section, and not any other.

If you cannot find my.cnf in /etc, run a find command to look on the whole disk for it.

```
find / -name my.cnf
```